# libc6 does not want to update to 2.29

Tags: debian, upgrade, glibc

I tried to install KiCad after i updated my Debian box to Debian 10, but i got the following error.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
kicad : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.28-10 is to be installed
         Recommends: kicad-libraries but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: kicad-doc-en but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After that i did `sudo apt update` and ran `apt-cache policy libc6` and got the following result.

```
libc6:
  Installed: 2.28-10
  Candidate: 2.28-10
  Version table:
 *** 2.28-10 500
        500 http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.24-11+deb9u4 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
     2.24-11+deb9u1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
```

So my question is how to i update libc6 from 2.28 to 2.29 so i can install KiCad, beacuse whenever i run `sudo apt upgrade libc6` i always get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc6 is already the newest version (2.28-10).
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Where did you get your KiCad package? It’s available in Debian and installs fine from the Debian repositories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing it on Stretch works with no issues as it depends on `libc6 2.24` which is the latest available for Stretch.

`libc6 2.28.10` is the latest version of `libc6` available for Buster. The only way to get 2.29 is to compile it from source and prepend the libraries to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. You can get it here: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/sources.html and then get `KiCad` from github: https://github.com/KiCad/kicad-packages3D/releases

You can also build an older version of `KiCad` from source via that same link that depends on `libc6 2.28`.

Keep in mind that the first method will most likely cause other things not to work properly because the system is very particular about having the right version of `libc6` installed. If you plan to compile it and prepend the libraries, make sure that you are doing it as a user with no `sudo` rights and not as `root`.

Lastly, Buster is not yet released and is, as of now, unsupported. It's possible that `libc6 2.29` will be released in the future for the `kicad` from the Debian repos.

Comment: Re your last point, Buster will release with glibc 2.28.

Comment: @StephenKitt Right, but the kiCad that he's trying to install requires `glibc 2.29`.